# How do I restrict one-off page access in a Confluence page

Tags: confluence

In Confluence, for just one page I would like to restrict access, to just me and my associate, (until the page is ready)

Is there any way to do this from within the page, or do I need to apply formal "Page Restrictions" which requires admin access :(

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Page+Restrictions there are the instructions. I'm pretty sure the page creator is the only person who can apply page restrictions aside from admins. If this works for you I'll create an answer

Comment: I am aware of that approach, but I was looking for something that does not require admin. I used to use a different wiki program, and right inside a page you could add something at the bottom like access:jjonnz, ntesler, etcetc. No admin rights required. I was hoping for something similar.

Comment: You don't HAVE to be an admin for that solution, but you would need 'restrict' permission. There are macros available which allow you to restrict specific pages by adding them on that page, but I don't know if you have any macros that can do this. While editing a page, look through your list of macros for one titled "add-page-restriction"

Answer (score 2):

If you have the {html} macro you could remove the edit command for everyone except you using javascript.

```
{hide-from:user=myname} 
{html}

<script type="text/javascript"> 
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {    
     AJS.$("#editPageLink").hide();    
});   
</script> 
{html}
{hide-from}
```

This will not prevent someone editing the page if they know how to get the page id and construct a url but it will prevent casual users from editing the page.

Comment: Cute! But I want to share it with a few others.

Comment: You could expand the user of {hide-from} to include groups or a list of users. 
e.g. {hide-from:groups=people-I-trust} or {show-to:users=myuserid,youruid,gfsuid,bffuid,xbffuid}

A Confluence Administrator could turn this into a macro.

Comment: Why would you want to hack a page like that? Just ask your wiki space or system administrator to give you `restrict access rights` ...

Comment: There are cases where setting page access rights via page code may be better than page rights. 

The take the example of a space with over 300 pages where all pages with TEAMLEADER in the page title can only be edited by the teamleader-edit group. Setting page restrictions for every page could be onerous. Or, this can be included on every page. 

I agree with your comment in that it is a hack. Still using CSS and JQuery to hide elements on a page can be useful.